# Dynamic mock creation from string (Java)

Tags: java, string, class, junit, mocking

For jUnit purposes, using Powermockito, I'm trying to create a TestUtility class that create mocks from a config file such as:

```
<automock>
  <mock id="1" class="com.aaa.MyClass">
    <method name="method1">
      <return type="String">ABC</return>
    </method>
    <method name="method2">
      <return type="boolean">false</return>
    </method>
  </mock>
</automock>
```

I would like that my TestUtility automatically creates the defined mock. It should be equivalent to:

```
MyClass mock = PowerMockito.mock(MyClass.class);
PowerMockito.when(mock.method1()).thenReturn("ABC");
PowerMockito.when(mock.method2()).thenReturn(false);
```

After loading MyClass, I get an exception when creating the mock:

```
Class clazz = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.aaa.MyClass");
Object mock = PowerMockito.mock(clazz);

>> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aaa.MyClass$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$8f25c857 cannot be cast to org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Factory
```

My goal is to have a kind of framework to automatically manage mocks and to prevent from writing so many PowerMockito.when(...).thenReturn(...) or PowerMockito.whenNew(...) when I'm dealing with complex classes.

Is there any way to prevent this exception or any workaround to mock an object from its class name (as a String)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should search for parametrised junit tests.

Comment: If you think you need to build such complicated mocks, you should probably question the design of your classes and your tests. Maybe your tests are checking implementation instead of public behaviour, or your classes are not as testable as they should be. If you invest your time in these areas, this will help you much more in the long run than the framework you are proposing. If you still want to go ahead, though, you could use Springframework to create your mocks.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I will check your frameworks.
I agree that classes are not as testable as I would like, but these classes I want to mock are not managed by me (and so cannot be modified).

The idea is to have component tests of a bunch of my classes (a feature I'm in charge of), fixing the behavior of other team's classes. All of that, with a "standardized" way of mocking (using this xml).

Comment: I don't see how XML can be better than Java code for this, since `when(mock.method1()).thenReturn("ABC");` is clearly shorter than `<method name="method1"><return type="String">ABC</return></method>`. Not to mention that using Java code is much more flexible and performant than XML.